# Assign Hours and Minutes from total minutes to tuple; Looking for succinct way to shorten code without using datetime module

Tags: python

Working on assignment for Python course which requires breaking down total minutes to hours and minutes without using the Datetime module.  The code I've written works fine, but I'm looking to shorten it.  There just seems to be too much code for such a simple task.  Again, I cannot import any modules for this task.

```
def total_minutes(mins):
    hours = mins / 60 # how many hours
    hours_rounded = (round(hours)) # round off the hours 
    rnd_hours_to_minutes = hours_rounded * 60 # multiply rounded hours and minutes
    remaining_mins = mins - rnd_hours_to_minutes # separate remaining minutes from hours
    if remaining_mins < 0: # have to have this statement because when minutes is between 30 and 60, shows negative number subtracting from 60
        remaining_mins += 60 # adding 60 minutes to the negative number to reflect actual minutes
        hours_rounded -= 1 # have to subtract hour since an hour is added when adding 60 minutes to negative number
    vars_to_tuple = (hours_rounded, remaining_mins) # assign vars to tuple
    print(vars_to_tuple) # will print hours and minutes in tuple; ex: (2, 59)

total_minutes(179)
```

Comment: This is off-topic IMO. There’s very little here but try Code Review, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

```
def hours_and_minutes(mins):
    hours = mins // 60
    minutes = mins % 60
    return hours, minutes
```